# Test both Handle and Handle<IFailed> methods with 1st level and 2nd Level Retry with Rebus

Tags: rebus, rebus-azureservicebus

How to debug both `Handle` methods below?

I set breakpoints on both `Handle` method within Visual Studio, and send message to `Subscriber1` queue, but both methods are not called under VS.

```
public class SomeHandler : IHandleMessages<string>, IHandleMessages<IFailed<string>>
{
    readonly IBus _bus;

    public SomeHandle(IBus bus)
    {
        _bus = bus;
    }

    public async Task Handle(string message)
    {
        // do stuff that can fail here...
    }

    public async Task Handle(IFailed<string> failedMessage)
    {
        await _bus.Advanced.TransportMessage.Defer(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(30));
    }
}
```

Below is the message sent to `Subscriber1`.

I tried sending the message excluding either `rbs2-msg-id` or `rbs2-msg-type`, neither of them triggers the `Handle` method above.

```
{
  "body": "Test",
   //other fields
  "properties": {
    "rbs2-intent": "pub",
    "rbs2-msg-id": "cd57d735-3989-45b5-8a3c-e457fa61dc94",
    "rbs2-return-address": "publisher",
    "rbs2-senttime": "2019-05-27T15:07:25.1770000+01:00",
    "rbs2-sender-address": "publisher",
    "rbs2-msg-type": "System.String, mscorlib",
    "rbs2-corr-id": "cd57d735-3989-45b5-8a3c-e457fa61dc94",
    "rbs2-corr-seq": "0",
    "rbs2-content-type": "application/json;charset=utf-8"
  },
  //other fields
}
```

**Update 1**

If an exception is thrown within `Handle(string message)`, the method will be retried based on the 1st level try count. This is what we need.

However, `Handle(IFailed<string> failedMessage)` is not invoked, how to debug `Handle(IFailed<string> failedMessage)` like abvoe?

**One note**: when an exception is thrown within `Handle(string message)`, IErrorHandler is NOT called, and AddTransportMessageForwarder is not called either, are these correct?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Could you try and check your logs?

When you remove the `rbs2-msg-id` header, Rebus will immediately move the message to the dead-letter queue, simply refusing to handle it. This is because a message without a message ID cannot be tracked by Rebus' error tracker.

If you remove the `rms2-msg-type` header, the serializer will most likely throw an error and not deserialize the incoming message.

In both cases, the error will be output to the logger.

And in both cases, the message body (`string` in this case, but it could be any message type`) cannot be constructed from the incoming`byte[]`, so Rebus cannot dispatch the message as either`string`not`IFailed`.

Edit after **Update 1**:

If your 2nd level retries do not kick in, it's most likely because you haven't enabled them:

```cs
Configure.With(...)
    .(...)
    .Options(o => o.SimpleRetryStrategy(secondLevelRetriesEnabled: true))
    .Start();
```

`IErrorHandler` is called when it is time to move the message to the dead-letter queue. You should see it being called, when all delivery attempts have failed (5 normal delivery attempts + 5 2nd level delivery attempts).

If you've configured things the way I suggested it, `AddTransportMessageForwarder` is used in another bus instance, which receives messages from the `error` queue. When `IErrorHandler` has been called, and the failed messge has been forwarded to the queue `error`, then your transport message forwarder should be called.

Comment: What you are saying is that on either case of removing `rbs2-msg-id` or `rms2-msg-type`, both `Handle` methods cannot be called. So is it there a way to debug this? Otherwise, how this method is tested when developing Rebus?

Comment: You can test it by having your code in the `Handle` method throw an exception. If you do that, then you should see retries.

Comment: Please see my Update 1 on OP.

Comment: Hi, do you have a chance to take a look at my Update 1 on OP.